# How do I Add a Tooltip To a DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tooltip, datagridtextcolumn

I'm using WPFtoolkit `DataGrid` ,I have to wrap text in a `DataGridTextColumn` or 
I have to add a `ToolTip` to the text column.  I have searched the net but i couldn't get a proper solution.  Expecting your valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 151):

Yes, you can add tooltip text to DataGridTextColumn - just stylize it

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ScreenName" Binding="{Binding ScreenName}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: for anyone on Silverlight, see [@MarkGladdling's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1977545/80428)

Comment: FYI, I struggled with this for a while until I realized that if "IsHitTestVisible" is set to FALSE on the datagrid tooltips don't work.

Comment: Can you add image and/or edit the background of the tooltip somehow when using this approach?

Comment: If you want the tooltip only at the column header, use `DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle` and the style's `TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader"`.

Answer (score 24):

I'm not sure if you can add a tooltip to a `DataGridTextColumn` but you can easily use the `DataGridTemplateColumn` and the `ToolTipService` instead. e.g.

```
<data:DataGrid.Columns>
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Broker">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Moniker.Abbreviation}"
                           ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Moniker.Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</data:DataGrid.Columns>
```

In this example `Moniker.Abbreviation` is displayed in the column. When the user hovers over a cell, the full broker name (`Moniker.Name`) is displayed in the tooltip.

Note: This example was taken from a Silverlight 3.0 application.

Comment: This also works in Silverlight, got here from top 3 hits from google search.  Of course change xml ns to 'sdk:' instead of 'data:' if your code matches the latest SL xaml templates.

Comment: Although I don't work with Silverlight, that is the only answer which also worked for me. The most popular answer results an exception in my application.