# Create ToolTip on Silverlight DataGridTextColumn that is different from the bound cell contents

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a `DataGridTextColumn` in a Silverlight 4 `DataGrid` and I want to set a ToolTip value on the column that is different from the bound value.

I know I can do this with a templated column quite easily - but it adds a huge amount of extra XAML and makes it cumbersome to read and maintain.

**This works, but is a lot of extra code - especially if ever need to change the template**

```
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="*">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding FullName}"
                 ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Email}" Width="Auto" Margin="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I'd like to find a nice way to do this with either a Style or inherited class. Like I said my main goal is to reduce bloat in the XAML for something so trivial as a tooltip in the best possible way.

There are a few similar stackoverflow questions with solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735573/unable-to-set-datagridcolumns-tooltip) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164288/how-do-i-add-tooltip-to-a-datagridtextcolumn), but they both show the same tooltip value as the contents of the cell (for instance when it overflows). While this is often what you want - I'm trying to show a different tooltip to the cell's contents.

I did find some [sample code for an inherited class](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/49099/237683.aspx) (scroll to end), which i tried to modify but got stuck becasue my XAML knowledge isn't up to par and I don't want to spend all night on this! This particular example appears like it works, but it looks like quite a hack and I think trying to modify it to work with two dependency properties is going to be an even bigger one.

PS. I would expect that a well written subclass would make it easy for me to bind other properties such as TextTrimming also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this style in your resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type data:DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding EMail}"/>
</Style>
```

To enable binding to any property, as you requested in the comment, you need to get creative. What I did was create two attached properties `ToolTipBinding` and `IsToolTipBindingEnabled`. The `ToolTipBinding` is set on the column to determine the tooltip, similar to the `Binding` property that determines the content of the cell, and the `IsToolTipBindingEnabled` is set to `true` on the `DataGridCell` object using a style similar to the one I mentioned above.

Then, I wrote code so that when the cell is loaded, the binding from its parent column is applied to its `ToolTip` property.

Here's the extension class:

```
public class DGExtensions
{
    public static object GetToolTipBinding(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(ToolTipBindingProperty);
    }

    public static void SetToolTipBinding(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ToolTipBindingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ToolTipBinding",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(DGExtensions),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static bool GetIsToolTipBindingEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsToolTipBindingEnabled);
    }

    public static void SetIsToolTipBindingEnabled(
        DependencyObject obj, 
        bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsToolTipBindingEnabled, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsToolTipBindingEnabled =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsToolTipBindingEnabled",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(DGExtensions),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsToolTipBindingEnabledChanged));

    public static void OnIsToolTipBindingEnabledChanged(
        DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = d as DataGridCell;
        if (cell == null) return;

        bool nv = (bool)e.NewValue, ov = (bool)e.OldValue;

        // Act only on an actual change of property value.
        if (nv == ov) return; 

        if (nv)
            cell.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(cell_Loaded);
        else
            cell.Loaded -= cell_Loaded;
    }

    static void cell_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell == null) return;
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(
                        cell.Column, ToolTipBindingProperty);
        if (binding == null) return;

        cell.SetBinding(DataGridCell.ToolTipProperty, binding);

        // This only gets called once, so remove the strong reference.
        cell.Loaded -= cell_Loaded;
    }
}
```

Example XAML usage:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
        <Setter 
            Property="dge:DGExtensions.IsToolTipBindingEnabled" 
            Value="True"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <tk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="PropA" 
                Binding="{Binding PropA}" 
                dge:DGExtensions.ToolTipBinding="{Binding PropB}"/>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="PropB" 
                Binding="{Binding PropB}"/>
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks, but what if i want to bind to something other than email

Comment: There you go, it took some creativity to get this right, might not be optimal, but it's good :-)

Comment: Just a quick comment, but I didn't think that Silverlight supported the `x:Type` in the `TargetType`?

Comment: @mark ya whats with that. i keep seeing all these examples with x:Type and i keep having to strip them all out!