# Show tooltip on data grid cell mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tooltip

I have a datagrid with multiple columns. I want to display a tooltip when user hovers the mouse on the cell of one of those columns.
Here is the code that I have tried:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PackageName}"  MinWidth="250" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StyleDataGridText}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E3E3E3"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Info}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Package Name"/>
            <Image x:Name="SortPackageNameImg" Source="{StaticResource SortupImg}" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="10,0,0,0"></Image>
            <Button Name="PackageNameFilterBtn" Click="PackageNameFilter_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/Resources/filter.png" Width="10" Height="10"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But this is not working. Is there anything I need to change to fix this?

Comment: check answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164288/how-do-i-add-a-tooltip-to-a-datagridtextcolumn

Comment: I have tried the same but it doesn't work for me. Looks like I am missing something.

Comment: Did you try @MarkGladding's answer? I think that should work for you. If it's not working, let me know

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? Does it work if you set the Value of the ToolTip property to a fixed value like "test"? And how is your "StyleDataGridText" defined?

Comment: What is in the style StyleDataGridText? also, what are properties of the DataGrid itself? For example, if IsHitTestVisible is set to false on the DataGrid, the tooltip will indeed not work.

Comment: Sorry, It was a type. Binding Info field should have been Binding ReleaseInfo. It fixed.